# cURL outputting the entire response

Tags: php, azure-cognitive-services

I'm using Microsoft Congnitive WebLM to word break a set of words, and it's outputting the entire cURL request, and I can't figure out how to use the results.

The code that I'm using:

```
$word = 'iwansttobreakfree';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,
    "https://api.projectoxford.ai/text/weblm/v1.0/breakIntoWords?model=query&text=" . $word);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: [subscription key removed for stack overflow]"
));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

var_dump($result);
```

The result's that I'm getting are

```
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 320
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
apim-request-id: ef73d48d-ab35-4fa5-a346-c57339415824
Date: Thu, 21 Jul 2016 20:00:12 GMT

{"candidates":[{"words":"i want to break free","probability":-7.1759999999999993},{"words":"iwant to break free","probability":-9.1660000000000021},{"words":"i want to breakfree","probability":-9.547},{"words":"i wan t to break free","probability":-9.8390000000000022},{"words":"iwanttobreakfree","probability":-9.877}]}
--------
bool(true)
```

Does anybody know how I can use the results json, with out outputting the whole cURL response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, really stupid mistakes :/

By setting `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` as `true` and setting `CURLOPT_HEADER` to `false` the json string is returned.

This is the new code:

```
$word = 'iwanttobreakfree';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,
    "https://api.projectoxford.ai/text/weblm/v1.0/breakIntoWords?model=query&text=" . $word);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: [key removed for stack overflow]"
));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo "\n--------\n";

$json = json_decode($result);
var_dump($json);
```

which results in this:

```
object(stdClass)#6 (1) {
  ["candidates"]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
      ["words"]=>
      string(20) "i want to break free"
      ["probability"]=>
      float(-7.176)
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
      ["words"]=>
      string(19) "iwant to break free"
      ["probability"]=>
      float(-9.166)
    }
    [2]=>
    object(stdClass)#3 (2) {
      ["words"]=>
      string(19) "i want to breakfree"
      ["probability"]=>
      float(-9.547)
    }
    [3]=>
    object(stdClass)#4 (2) {
      ["words"]=>
      string(21) "i wan t to break free"
      ["probability"]=>
      float(-9.839)
    }
    [4]=>
    object(stdClass)#5 (2) {
      ["words"]=>
      string(16) "iwanttobreakfree"
      ["probability"]=>
      float(-9.877)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
```

To this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
```

[image]

Check out the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: lol, I think it was one of those `code block` moment's, after having a brew it was clear :)

Comment: Happens to me all the time.